# PHP find and replace multiple words given by input text separated by pipe symbol

Tags: php, arrays, str-replace

I have input text to find and replace words separated by pipe.
For example, I need to find lorem and ipsum.
So I separated with pipe(|) and put `lorem|ipsum` on `$_POST['find']` to get replaced into something like {lorem} and {ipsum}.

String:

> lorem ipsum doler sit amet. Amet ipsum doleram paradem

```
$find = $_POST['find']; //user want to search lorem|ipsum
$find = explode('|', $find); // to array
$replace = '{'.implode('|', $find).'}'; // i expect soething like array('{lorem}','{ipsum}');
$newString = str_replace($find, $replace, $string);
```

Output

> {lorem|{lorem|ipsum}} {lorem|ipsum} doler sit amet. Amet {lorem|ipsum}
>   doleram paradem

What I expect

```
{lorem} {ipsum} doler sit amet. Amet {ipsum} doleram paradem
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't implode the replacement like that.
The way you did returns one string, what you need is an array of strings.

Looping or array_map the find and adding the curly braces is what you need.

```
$str = "lorem ipsum doler sit amet. Amet ipsum doleram paradem";

$find = "lorem|ipsum";
$find = explode('|', $find);
foreach($find as $f){
    $replace[] = "{" . $f . "}";
}

$newString = str_replace($find, $replace, $str);
echo $newString;
```

Output:

```
{lorem} {ipsum} doler sit amet. Amet {ipsum} doleram paradem
```

https://3v4l.org/DOB2F

---

Since both array_map and foreach is looping, I add a non looping version too.

I replace `|` with `}|{` and then explode on `|` which leave curly braced strings in the array.

```
$find = "lorem|ipsum";
$replstr = "{" . str_replace("|", "}|{", $find) ."}";
$find = explode('|', $find);

$replace = explode("|", $replstr);

$newString = str_replace($find, $replace, $str);
echo $newString;
```

https://3v4l.org/E4O11

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative solution I was writing:

```
$input = 'lorem|ipsum';
$string = 'lorem ipsum doler sit amet. Amet ipsum doleram paradem';

// We get the words to replace
$find = explode('|', $input);

// We make sure the user didn't enter a word twice, (something like: lorem|lorem)
$find = array_unique($find);

// Prepare the replacement
$replace = array_map(function ($item) {
    return '{'.$item.'}';
}, $find);

// Finally do the replacement
$result = str_replace($find, $replace, $string);

echo $result; // {lorem} {ipsum} doler sit amet. Amet {ipsum} doleram paradem
```